# Bluetooth Connection and Receive/Display Data on Screen

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to connect my android phone to a `Bluetooth` chip on a circuit connected to a sonar sensor. The sensor/circuit is programmed to accept a connection and continuously display data in the form of a message. My code allows me to connect but it won't display data on the screen. Help?

Below you can find my java code.

```
public class ConnectThread extends Activity {
    static BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    static BluetoothSocket mmSocket2;
    static BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    static BluetoothDevice mmDevice2;
    static InputStream mmInputStream;
    static OutputStream mmOutputStream;
    static BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    static BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter2;
    TextView myLabel;
    TextView Display;
    static volatile boolean stopWorker;
    static Thread workerThread;
    static byte[] readBuffer;
    static int readBufferPosition;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect_thread);

    Button button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    myLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Display);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(ConnectThread.this, "Connection in progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            myLabel.setText("Connection in progress");
            try 
            {
                 findBT();
                 openBT();

            }
            catch (IOException ex) { }
           }        
         });}



        void findBT() 
        {


            mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
            {
                myLabel.setText("No bluetooth adapter available");
            }

            if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
            {
                Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
            }

            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
            if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
            {
                for(BluetoothDevice device1 : pairedDevices)
                {
                    if(device1.getName().equals("HC-05")) 
                    {
                        mmDevice = device1;
                        myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Device Found");
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(pairedDevices.size()==0){myLabel.setText("Please Pair devices");}
            }




        }
        public int openBT() throws IOException
        {
            UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
            mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);        
            mmSocket.connect();
            mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
            mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();


            return 1;
        }

        void ListenForData()
        {
            final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
            final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

            stopWorker = false;
            readBufferPosition = 0;
            readBuffer = new byte[1024];
            workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {                
                   while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
                   {
                        try 
                        {
                            int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();                        
                            if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                            {
                                byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                                mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                                for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                                {
                                    byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                    if(b == delimiter)
                                    {
                                        byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                        System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                        final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                        readBufferPosition = 0;

                                        handler.post(new Runnable()
                                        {
                                            public void run()
                                            {
                                                Display.setText(data);

                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } 
                        catch (IOException ex) 
                        {
                            stopWorker = true;
                        }
                   }
                }
            });

            workerThread.start();
        }



        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action))
            { myLabel.setText("CONNECTED");}
        }
        void closeBT() throws IOException
    {
        stopWorker = true;
        mmOutputStream.close();
        mmInputStream.close();
        mmSocket.close();
        myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Closed");
    }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your message using handler like:

```
public static final int MESSAGE_PROGRESS = 1;
public static final String TOAST = "toast";


Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(ConnectThread.MESSAGE_PROGRESS);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(ConnectThread.TOAST, progressMessage);
msg.setData(bundle);
mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

and set Text with help of handler like:

```
String data;
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
void handleMessage(Message msg) {
switch (msg.what) {
    case MESSAGE_TOAST:
     if(data = msg.getData().getString(TOAST)) {
        Display.setText(data);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Where do I place the above code in my code? Under which methods? Also are any of the variables in that code for me to fill in?

Comment: Put the first sendMessage(msg) code where you read bytes from inputStream.. And make handler into your Activity to receive those message means put the second code at end of Activity not into any method..

Comment: What should I change BluetoothMain to?

Comment: Still not sure how to add in these changes and get my code to compile?